# run cron job only when machine is idle (linux)

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron, centos

How can I run a cron job(bash script) only when CPU idle >50%?

I can get cpu idle from TOP

```
top -b -d 00.10 -n 3 |grep ^Cpu
Cpu(s): 0.3%us, 0.3%sy, 0.0%ni, 99.3%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
```

my current setup is:

```
crontab
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/batchprocess.php
# I could use a bash script here to call PHP, if it is a good solution.
```

And I have the PHP script check for CPU idle:

```
batchprocess.php
proc_nice(10);
// wait for CPU idle
do{
    $cpu_stat = exec('top -b -d 00.10 -n 3 |grep ^Cpu');    
    $tmp = stristr($cpu_stat,'%id',TRUE);
    $cpuidle = trim(substr($tmp,strrpos($tmp,',')+1));
}while($cpuidle<$min_cpuidle);
// do actual processing here
```

The problem with my current method is it starts the program regardless of CPU utilization.  And the while loop running TOP feels not efficient. I wish it only starts when CPU idle>50

Some additional info:

- Centos 6.2, PHP5.3
- I have a few EC2 instances that never shuts down, so I want to utilize their processing power when idle. But never load the server heavily. (redundancy DB instance, Development instance, NAT instance)
- I know EC2 auto scaling, spot instance.  Just want to use the extra capacity.
- the background job is image compression (CPU intensive, not much I/O or network).

Any suggestion is welcome. thanks in advance!

---

Based on the input below, I realized that "nice" is a better solution in my case.  I should re-align my objective to minimize impact to the server instead of tracing CPU utilization.

So the new setup is:

```
crontab
0,15,30,45 * * * * nice -20 /usr/bin/php /home/user/batchprocess.php
```

And PHP script:

```
batchprocess.php
if ($cpuidle < 50) 
    exit(0);
// do actual processing here
```

I'll test it and post back my finding.

---

report back:  I have put this code through DEV/PRD, it works quite well.  It does not solve the problem of TOCTOU but is good enough for now.

Comment: idle one second 100% the next, how about using nice on you cronjob to set its priority

Comment: @Dagon Since I have no better solution, check at run time is at least better than doing nothing. e.g. starting the job when system is already busy.

Comment: this is neither here nor there but omg why are you writing cronjobs in php

Comment: @Eevee The batch job uses amazon AWS sdk, mySQL and imagick.  So PHP is the way I can get it to work. I don't know any ruby/perl/python unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical case of [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) - you check if the system is idle, and start your process - but after your check, as or before your process starts, something else caused another process in the system to kick off and you still load the system more than necessary.

The "correct" way to do this is to give your process a low priority, using the `nice` command. By the way, your loop to check cpu usage will use 100% cpu, so it probably wouldn't work unless THE FIRST time you check it's idle.

You already have a "proc_nice(10)", so that should do the job. I don't see any point in spending effort in identifying whether the system is busy or not.

If you watned to, at suitable points in your code, you could do something like:

```
 if (check_cpu_usage() > 50%) sleep(1second);
```

But I'm not sure if that's much use - if the system is busy, a "nice" process won't receive much CPU-time, and thus won't compete with other processes that run at higher priority.

Comment: Thanks for the extended info.  I was not considering how "nice" the process is in practice. Will higher priority process put it into halt for a long time?  e.g. running full DB backup.

Comment: If you make it "very nice" (`nice -n 20` on the command line) then it will definitely use very little CPU _IF_ there is something else that wants to run. I used to do this for some calculations I liked to do [that took many, many hours]. The difference when compiling a Linux kernel was not noticable, but as soon as the compilation finished, the calculation would kick in again ans do it's job.

Comment: The combination of cron and a low priority job could theoretically result in multiple low-running instances of the job running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wish to have your script executed whenever the system load is e.g. 2.0 or less, you could use a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOAD=`cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d" " -f1`
THRESHOLD=2.0
if [ $(bc <<< "$LOAD <= $THRESHOLD") -eq 1 ]; then
    $@
fi
```

Save it as e.g. `/usr/local/bin/if-idle`, and stick `if-idle` in front of your command in your crontab file.

Comment: That still is just "what is the system doing now", it may well change in the next clock-tick.

Comment: True, but this approach also has valid use cases. Imagine a situation where the cron job needs to hold a lock for a shared resource. In this case, running the job with `nice -20` comes with the risk of locking the shared resource for an arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: This is great for cases when I am running one CPU-intense batch of computations and want to defer starting the next one when the first one will have finished, without knowing when it will happen, and without access to the terminal where it is running.